# How do i copy old columns to my new existing table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an existing new table that has no columns yet. I want to copy all 10 columns in my old table. How do i do that? I don't want to drop the table so I could perform: `create table newTable as select * from oldTable`.

Comment: You cannot have a table with no columns ! But if you are asking how to copy the definition of one table to another, including any data, then you are correct: create table newTable a select * from oldTable

Comment: Stablish the table column first i guess. Before you insert a value.

Comment: `create table as select` doesn't "drop" the old table. What exactly is your problem with using that?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to drop the table so I could perform:
>   create table newTable as select * from oldTable.

Assuming your new table has at least 1 column `BobC` told you cannot have a table without any column, you can alter your table.

```
Alter new_table add (col1 varchar2(10)) , col2 ...);
```

Note that you need to mention all the column same as old table manually here.

If you don't want to do this manually then probably you would need a PLSQL block to do this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE creat_tbl_frm_tbl (tablname VARCHAR2)
AS
   db_user    VARCHAR2 (100) := USER;

   TYPE t_rec IS RECORD
   (
      COLUMN_NAME   VARCHAR2 (30 BYTE),
      DATA_TYPE     VARCHAR2 (106 BYTE),
      DATA_LENGTH   NUMBER
   );

   TYPE t_record IS TABLE OF t_rec;

   -- initialization of record
   v_record   t_record := t_record ();
   v_cntr     NUMBER := 0;
   v_status   NUMBER;
   sql_stmt   VARCHAR2 (2000);
BEGIN
   ---dropping Already Existing temporary table

   BEGIN
      SELECT 1
        INTO v_status
        FROM all_objects
       WHERE UPPER (object_name) = UPPER (tablname) AND owner = db_user;

      --dbms_output.put_line( v_status );

      IF v_status = 1
      THEN
         sql_stmt := 'drop table  ' || tablname || '_new';

         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
      END IF;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Table not found--' || tablname);
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
            'Error while dropping table-' || SQLCODE || SQLERRM);
   END;


   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ---- retrieving the columns of the table
   BEGIN
        SELECT column_name, data_type, data_length
          BULK COLLECT INTO v_record
          FROM all_tab_columns
         WHERE table_name = UPPER (tablname)
      ORDER BY column_id;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
            'Error while retrieving the column details-' || SQLCODE || SQLERRM);
   END;


   FOR i IN 1 .. v_record.COUNT
   LOOP
      v_cntr := v_cntr + 1;

      IF v_cntr = 1
      THEN
         IF    v_record (i).data_type = 'DATE'
            OR UPPER (v_record (i).data_type) = 'TIMESTAMP(6)'
         THEN
            sql_stmt :=
                  'create table '
               || ' '
               || tablname
               || '_new'
               || '('
               || v_record (i).column_name
               || ' '
               || v_record (i).data_type
               || ')';
         ELSE
            sql_stmt :=
                  'create table '
               || ' '
               || tablname
               || '_new'
               || '('
               || v_record (i).column_name
               || ' '
               || v_record (i).data_type
               || '('
               || v_record (i).data_length
               || '))';
         END IF;

         --dbms_output.put_line(sql_stmt);
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
      ELSE
         IF    v_record (i).data_type = 'DATE'
            OR UPPER (v_record (i).data_type) = 'TIMESTAMP(6)'
         THEN
            sql_stmt :=
                  'alter table'
               || ' '
               || tablname
               || '_new'
               || ' '
               || 'add ('
               || v_record (i).column_name
               || ' '
               || v_record (i).data_type
               || ')';
         ELSE
            sql_stmt :=
                  'alter table'
               || ' '
               || tablname
               || '_new'
               || ' '
               || 'add ('
               || v_record (i).column_name
               || ' '
               || v_record (i).data_type
               || '('
               || v_record (i).data_length
               || '))';
         END IF;

         --dbms_output.put_line(sql_stmt);
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Process Completed Successfully..!!');
END;
```

Output:

```
SQL>  exec creat_tbl_frm_tbl('table2')
Process Completed Successfully..!!

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from table2;

no rows selected

-- This is created with same columns as of passed table table2
SQL> select * from table2_new;     
no rows selected
```

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3 --...
INTO newTable
FROM oldTable
```

Comment: That's invalid for Oracle (and invalid standard SQL)

Comment: There was no oracle badge there when I replied ;)

Comment: The `oracle` tag was there from the beginning. But that isn't a valid answer for a question tagged `sql` either - because that is non-standard SQL and the `sql` tag refers to "standard SQL" not to a specific DBMS product

Comment: That's just ridiculous. Switching to a completely different system isn't a realistic solution.